# Storing data in files even if the program is closed in Python

Tags: python, file, save

I'm working for a school project and I can't seem to find the answers for this. The main trouble with my assignment is to:

> Make sure to use Python's file handling capabilities to ensure that data is persistent even after the program stops running.

How can I make it so that I can update my lists through the data stored in my file? By this I mean that I would edit my list in my while loop, save it to the file, and then change the list based on what is written in the file. I also cannot use tkinter for this project. This is my current code:

```
library_list = ["Lord of the Flies", "Cat in the Hat", "Green Eggs and Ham", "One Fish Two Fish"]
user_list = []
checkout = False
f = open("savedata.txt", "w")

#username = school
#password = password
user_check = input("What is your username \n")
password_check = input("\n" + "What is your password?")


while checkout == False:
   option = input("Welcome to the library. What book would you like to borrow?" + str(library_list))
   if option in library_list:
       library_list.remove(option)
       user_list.append(option)
       LIBRARY_LIST = library_list
       USER_LIST = user_list
       print("Library catalogue:" + str(library_list) + "\n" + "Borrowed books:" + str(user_list))
       f.write(str(LIBRARY_LIST) + "\n" + str(USER_LIST))
       orderConfirm = input("Would you like to borrow another book? (y/n)")

       # Pathways converge after user confirms order.
       if orderConfirm.lower() == "n":
        print("Thanks for coming!")
        break
       else:
        print("Okay, here is our catalogue.")

   elif option in user_list:
       print("I'm sorry, this item is currently borrowed by someone else. Please try again later.")

   else:
       print("This item is not in the library. Try again.")`
```

Thank you.

I tried to use the following code but it just skips over it.

```
with open("savelist.txt", "r") as f:
   for line in f:
      print(line)
```

Comment: `f = open("savedata.txt", "w")` will wipe out anything already in the file ... so first you need to load the data from the file into something ... in order to write it back out with your modified data

Answer (score 1):

make your initial data first

```
import json
INITIAL_LIST = []
# if the savefile is not yet created
if not os.path.exists("/path/to/savefile.dat"):
   with open("/path/to/savefile.dat","wb") as f:
      # save initial list
      json.dump(INITIAL_LIST,f)
```

then open and read in your "saved data"

```
library_list = json.load(open("/path/to/savefile.dat","rb"))
```

then modify your list

```
# add a book
library_list.append(new_book_data)
```

then save it at regular intervals

```
with open("/path/to/savefile.dat","wb") as f:
    json.dump(library_list,f)
```

this is one potential way to accomplish this task